# Pointers in C: when to use the ampersand and the asterisk?

Tags: c, pointers

I'm just starting out with pointers, and I'm slightly confused. I know `&` means the address of a variable and that `*` can be used in front of a pointer variable to get the value of the object that is pointed to by the pointer. But things work differently when you're working with arrays, strings or when you're calling functions with a pointer copy of a variable. It's difficult to see a pattern of logic inside all of this.

When should I use `&` and `*`?

Comment: Please illustrate how you see things sometimes working differently.  Otherwise, we have to guess what it is that's confusing you.

Comment: Agree with Neil Butterworth. Probably gonna get much more info getting it first hand from a book, and the K&R explanation is quite clear.

Comment: Though it *is* a hard topic to search on this has been discussed over and over  again in various guises. The following are all taken from http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=c+pointer+basic and are probably relevant (I'm sure there a duplicate, but I haven't found it): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727/what-are-the-barriers-to-understanding-pointers-and-what-can-be-done-to-overcome http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897366/how-do-pointer-to-pointers-work-in-c http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162941/why-use-pointers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500886/how-to-approach-pointers-in-c

Comment: I disagree with all of you who say that its not a good idea to ask these types of questions on SO. SO has become the number 1 resource when searching on Google. You're not giving enough credit to these answers. Read Dan Olson's response. This answer is truly insightful and incredibly helpful to newbies. `RTFM` is unhelpful, and quite frankly very rude. If you don't have time to answer, then be respectful of those who take time to answer these questions. I wish I could @ this to "anon" but obviously he / she doesn't have the time to contribute in any meaningful way.

Comment: What [SSH This](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1079602/ssh-this) said is absolutely true. Some people shout "Just Google it", but nowadays it's the other way around: "Just look on StackOverflow." This question is useful for many people. (Hence the upvotes and no downvotes.)

Comment: https://beej.us/blog/data/c-pointers/

Answer (score 745, accepted):

You have pointers and values:

```
int* p; // variable p is pointer to integer type
int i; // integer value
```

You turn a pointer into a value with `*`:

```
int i2 = *p; // integer i2 is assigned with integer value that pointer p is pointing to
```

You turn a value into a pointer with `&`:

```
int* p2 = &i; // pointer p2 will point to the integer i
```

Edit:
In the case of arrays, they are treated very much like pointers.  If you think of them as pointers, you'll be using `*` to get at the values inside of them as explained above, but there is also another, more common way using the `[]` operator:

```
int a[2];  // array of integers
int i = *a; // the value of the first element of a
int i2 = a[0]; // another way to get the first element
```

To get the second element:

```
int a[2]; // array
int i = *(a + 1); // the value of the second element
int i2 = a[1]; // the value of the second element
```

So the `[]` indexing operator is a special form of the `*` operator, and it works like this:

```
a[i] == *(a + i);  // these two statements are the same thing
```

Comment: How come this doesn't work? `int aX[] = {3, 4}; int *bX = &aX;`

Comment: Arrays are special and can be converted to pointers transparently.  This highlights another way to get from a pointer to a value, I'll add it to the explanation above.

Comment: If I understand this correctly... the example `int *bX = &aX;` doesn't work because the `aX` already returns the address of `aX[0]` (i.e. `&aX[0]`), so `&aX` would get the address of an address which makes no sense. Is this correct?

Comment: You're correct, although there are cases where you may actually want the address of the address.  In that case you'd declare it as int** bX = &aX, but this is a more advanced topic.

Comment: Pieter: Sort of - there's actually two special cases when an array used in an expression is *not* replaced by a pointer to the first element - that's when the array is the subject of either the unary `&` or the `sizeof` operators.  So `&ax` is actually taking the address *of the array itself* (rather than being the address of an address).  This is a pretty unusual case - you will quite probably never need to do that.

Comment: @Dan, given `int aX[] = {3,4};`, `int **bX = &aX;` is an error.  `&aX` is of type "pointer to array [2] of `int`", not "pointer to pointer to `int`".  Specifically, an array's name is not treated as a pointer to its first element for unary `&`.  You can do: `int (*bX)[2] = &aX;`

Comment: How does this work when the pointer is contained inside a struct? Obviously you access the struct through a pointer, but I'm still confused.

Comment: "You turn a pointer into a value" is a terrible description.  You find the value referenced by the pointer with `*`.  The pointer is a variable which contains a value, and the value it contains is the address of some memory location.  There's no "conversion", and the pointer is not "turned into" the value it refers to.  Similarly, `&` does not "turn a value into a pointer".  `&v` evaluates to the address of `v`. There's no conversion.

Comment: And, one of the amusing parts of C: because of the equivalence of `p[i]` and `*(p+i)`, combined with the equivalence of `p+i` and `i+p` since `+` is commutative, indexing is perfectly commutative: `"abc"[1] == 1["abc"]` always holds. (Unfortunately the right side will not pass review.)

Answer (score 40):

There is a pattern when dealing with arrays and functions; it's just a little hard to see at first.

When dealing with arrays, it's useful to remember the following: when an array expression appears in most contexts, the type of the expression is implicitly converted from "N-element array of T" to "pointer to T", and its value is set to point to the first element in the array.  The exceptions to this rule are when the array expression appears as an operand of either the `&` or `sizeof` operators, or when it is a string literal being used as an initializer in a declaration.

Thus, when you call a function with an array expression as an argument, the function will receive a pointer, not an array:

```
int arr[10];
...
foo(arr);
...

void foo(int *arr) { ... }
```

This is why you *don't* use the `&` operator for arguments corresponding to "%s" in `scanf()`:

```
char str[STRING_LENGTH];
...
scanf("%s", str);
```

Because of the implicit conversion, `scanf()` receives a `char *` value that points to the beginning of the `str` array.  This holds true for any function called with an array expression as an argument (just about any of the `str*` functions, `*scanf` and `*printf` functions, etc.).

In practice, you will probably never call a function with an array expression using the `&` operator, as in:

```
int arr[N];
...
foo(&arr);

void foo(int (*p)[N]) {...}
```

Such code is not very common; you have to know the size of the array in the function declaration, and the function only works with pointers to arrays of specific sizes (a pointer to a 10-element array of T is a different type than a pointer to a 11-element array of T).

When an array expression appears as an operand to the `&` operator, the type of the resulting expression is "pointer to N-element array of T", or `T (*)[N]`, which is different from an array of pointers (`T *[N]`) and a pointer to the base type (`T *`).

When dealing with functions and pointers, the rule to remember is: if you want to change the value of an argument and have it reflected in the calling code, you must pass a pointer to the thing you want to modify.  Again, arrays throw a bit of a monkey wrench into the works, but we'll deal with the normal cases first.

Remember that C passes *all* function arguments by value; the formal parameter receives a copy of the value in the actual parameter, and any changes to the formal parameter are not reflected in the actual parameter.  The common example is a swap function:

```
void swap(int x, int y) { int tmp = x; x = y; y = tmp; }
...
int a = 1, b = 2;
printf("before swap: a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
swap(a, b);
printf("after swap: a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
```

You'll get the following output:

```
before swap: a = 1, b = 2
after swap: a = 1, b = 2
```

The formal parameters `x` and `y` are distinct objects from `a` and `b`, so changes to `x` and `y` are not reflected in `a` and `b`.  Since we want to modify the values of `a` and `b`, we must pass *pointers* to them to the swap function:

```
void swap(int *x, int *y) {int tmp = *x; *x = *y; *y = tmp; }
...
int a = 1, b = 2;
printf("before swap: a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
swap(&a, &b);
printf("after swap: a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
```

Now your output will be

```
before swap: a = 1, b = 2
after swap: a = 2, b = 1
```

Note that, in the swap function, we don't change the values of `x` and `y`, but the values of what `x` and `y` *point to*.  Writing to `*x` is different from writing to `x`; we're not updating the value in `x` itself, we get a location from `x` and update the value in that location.

This is equally true if we want to modify a pointer value; if we write

```
int myFopen(FILE *stream) {stream = fopen("myfile.dat", "r"); }
...
FILE *in;
myFopen(in);
```

then we're modifying the value of the input parameter `stream`, not what `stream` *points to*, so changing `stream` has no effect on the value of `in`; in order for this to work, we must pass in a pointer to the pointer:

```
int myFopen(FILE **stream) {*stream = fopen("myFile.dat", "r"); }
...
FILE *in;
myFopen(&in);
```

Again, arrays throw a bit of a monkey wrench into the works.  When you pass an array expression to a function, what the function receives is a pointer.  Because of how array subscripting is defined, you can use a subscript operator on a pointer the same way you can use it on an array:

```
int arr[N];
init(arr, N);
...
void init(int *arr, int N) {size_t i; for (i = 0; i < N; i++) arr[i] = i*i;}
```

Note that array objects may not be assigned; i.e., you can't do something like

```
int a[10], b[10];
...
a = b;
```

so you want to be careful when you're dealing with pointers to arrays; something like

```
void (int (*foo)[N])
{
  ...
  *foo = ...;
}
```

won't work.

Answer (score 32):

Put simply

- `&` means the **address-of**, you will see that in placeholders for functions to modify the parameter variable as in C, parameter variables are passed by value, using the ampersand means to pass by reference.
- `*` means the **dereference** of a pointer variable, meaning to get the value of that pointer variable.

```
int foo(int *x){
   *x++;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   int y = 5;
   foo(&y);  // Now y is incremented and in scope here
   printf("value of y = %d\n", y); // output is 6
   /* ... */
}
```

The above example illustrates how to call a function `foo` by using pass-by-reference, compare with this

```
int foo(int x){
   x++;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
   int y = 5;
   foo(y);  // Now y is still 5
   printf("value of y = %d\n", y); // output is 5
   /* ... */
}
```

Here's an illustration of using a **dereference**

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
   int y = 5;
   int *p = NULL;
   p = &y;
   printf("value of *p = %d\n", *p); // output is 5
}
```

The above illustrates how we got the **address-of** `y` and assigned it to the pointer variable `p`. Then we **dereference** `p` by attaching the `*` to the front of it to obtain the value of `p`, i.e. `*p`.

Answer (score 20):

Yeah that can be quite complicated since the `*` is used for many different purposes in C/C++.

If `*` appears in front of an already declared variable/function, it means either that:

- a) `*` gives access to the value of that variable (if the type of that variable is a pointer type, or overloaded the `*` operator).
- b) `*` has the meaning of the multiply operator, in that case, there has to be another variable to the left of the `*`

If `*` appears in a variable or function declaration it means that that variable is a pointer:

```
int int_value = 1;
int * int_ptr; //can point to another int variable
int   int_array1[10]; //can contain up to 10 int values, basically int_array1 is an pointer as well which points to the first int of the array
//int   int_array2[]; //illegal, without initializer list..
int int_array3[] = {1,2,3,4,5};  // these two
int int_array4[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}; // are identical

void func_takes_int_ptr1(int *int_ptr){} // these two are identical
void func_takes_int_ptr2(int int_ptr[]){}// and legal
```

If `&` appears in a variable or function declaration, it generally means that that variable is a reference to a variable of that type.

If `&` appears in front of an already declared variable, it returns the address of that variable

Additionally you should know, that when passing an array to a function, you will always have to pass the array size of that array as well, except when the array is something like a 0-terminated cstring (char array).

Comment: @akmozo s/func_takes int_ptr2/func_takes_int_ptr2/ (invalid space)

Answer (score 10):

I was looking through all the wordy explanations so instead turned to a video from University of New South Wales for rescue.Here is the simple explanation: if we have a cell that has address `x` and value `7`, the indirect way to ask for address of value `7` is `&7` and the indirect way to ask for value at address `x` is `*x`.So `(cell: x , value: 7) == (cell: &7 , value: *x)` .Another way to look into it: `John` sits at `7th seat`.The `*7th seat` will point to `John` and `&John` will give `address`/location of the `7th seat`. This simple explanation helped me and hope it will help others as well. Here is the link for the excellent video: [click here.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rxvv9krECNw)

Here is another example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{ 
    int x;            /* A normal integer*/
    int *p;           /* A pointer to an integer ("*p" is an integer, so p
                       must be a pointer to an integer) */

    p = &x;           /* Read it, "assign the address of x to p" */
    scanf( "%d", &x );          /* Put a value in x, we could also use p here */
    printf( "%d\n", *p ); /* Note the use of the * to get the value */
    getchar();
}
```

**Add-on:**  Always initialize pointer before using them.If not, the pointer will point to anything, which might result in crashing the program because the operating system will prevent you from accessing the memory it knows you don't own.But simply putting  `p = &x;`, we are assigning the pointer a specific location.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you have it down pat, there's nothing more you need to know :-)

I would just add the following bits:

- the two operations are opposite ends of the spectrum. `&` takes a variable and gives you the address, `*` takes an address and gives you the variable (or contents).
- arrays "degrade" to pointers when you pass them to functions.
- you can actually have multiple levels on indirection (`char **p` means that `p` is a pointer to a pointer to a `char`.

As to things working differently, not really:

- arrays, as already mentioned, degrade to pointers (to the first element in the array) when passed to functions; they don't preserve size information.
- there are no strings in C, just character arrays that, by convention, represent a string of characters terminated by a zero (`\0`) character.
- When you pass the address of a variable to a function, you can de-reference the pointer to change the variable itself (normally variables are passed by value (except for arrays)).

Answer (score 6):

I think you are a bit confused. You should read a good tutorial/book on pointers.

[This](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter5/pointers.html) tutorial is very good for starters(clearly explains what `&` and `*` are). And yeah don't forget to read the book **Pointers in C** by Kenneth Reek.

The difference between `&` and `*` is very clear.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int x, *p;

  p = &x;         /* initialise pointer(take the address of x) */
  *p = 0;         /* set x to zero */
  printf("x is %d\n", x);
  printf("*p is %d\n", *p);

  *p += 1;        /* increment what p points to i.e x */
  printf("x is %d\n", x);

  (*p)++;         /* increment what p points to i.e x */
  printf("x is %d\n", x);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

When you are declaring a pointer variable or function parameter, use the *:

```
int *x = NULL;
int *y = malloc(sizeof(int)), *z = NULL;
int* f(int *x) {
    ...
}
```

NB: each declared variable needs its own *.

When you want to take the address of a value, use &. When you want to read or write the value in a pointer, use *.

```
int a;
int *b;
b = f(&a);
a = *b;

a = *f(&a);
```

Arrays are usually just treated like pointers. When you declare an array parameter in a function, you can just as easily declare it is a pointer (it means the same thing). When you pass an array to a function, you are actually passing a pointer to the first element.

Function pointers are the only things that don't quite follow the rules. You can take the address of a function without using &, and you can call a function pointer without using *.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, looks like your post got editted...

```
double foo[4];
double *bar_1 = &foo[0];
```

See how you can use the `&` to get the address of the beginning of the array structure?  The following

```
Foo_1(double *bar, int size){ return bar[size-1]; }
Foo_2(double bar[], int size){ return bar[size-1]; }
```

will do the same thing.

Comment: The question has  been tagged C not C++.

Comment: And I've removed the offending cout <<

Answer (score 1):

Understanding pointers is complicate at first, you have to make exercises and
practice a lot.
Don't expect to catch it at the first iteration or expect to read an explanation
and think that you have understood, because very likely you did not...

If you want more than just theoretical understanding I suggest to follow this
course from Stanford CS107 and practice given exercises,
at least follow the first three lessons where pointers are explained.

[Stanford CS107 by Jerry Cain](https://see.stanford.edu/Course/CS107)

Another very valuable tool is `gdb` where you have an interactive
shell like you have, for example, in python.
With `gdb` you can play and experiment:

```
 (gdb) x pp.name
0x555555555060 <_start>:        0x8949ed31
(gdb) x &pp.name
0x7fffffffdc38: 0x55555060
(gdb) p &pp.name
$4 = (char **) 0x7fffffffdc38
(gdb) p *pp.name
$5 = 49 '1'
```