# difference between int f(int &x) int f(int x)

Tags: c++, recursion

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int f(int & ,int );//function prototype

main()
{
  int x,p=5; //p is initialized to 5
  x=f(p,p);
  printf("\n Value is : %d",x);//print the value of x
  getch();
}

int f (int & x, int c)
{
c=c-1;
if (c==0) return 1;
x=x+1;
return f(x,c) * x; //recursion
}
```

output : 6561

can anyone explain me the flow the program
This question is from gate i couldn't understand it. It seems that the function is called with value of p = 5. It is catched in the function f by int &x the problem is here. Is the value i.e 5 is stored in x or in address of x.

Comment: This is not C, the `int &` syntax is C++.

Comment: even i appeared for Gate yesterday and was unable to understand this question. Hope someone can explain this.

Comment: @user2060893 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877052/use-of-the-operator-in-c-function-signatures take a look at this question

Answer (score 7):

This code uses a [C++ *reference*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29), which is what the `int &` syntax means.

A reference is, basically, [syntactic sugar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntactic_sugar) for a pointer. So when you call `f(p, p)`, the function argument `x` is a reference to `p` in `main()`, while `c` is merely a copy of the value at the time of the call.

This means `f` can change the value of `p` in `main()`, through the reference. Since `f` calls itself recursively, passing the same reference toitself, it's always a reference to the `p` in `main()`.

To track the recusion, I would suggest adding logging print-outs at strategic places inside `f()`.

Answer (score 0):

The first creates a `reference` which is more like a cleaner syntax instead of a pointer.

You can use it to change contents of variables among calls to function.

Although you must note, the code you have posted is not valid C++. C++ does not allow `main` without a return type.

Answer (score 0):

More simple:

```
int f(int &a){
  a = 5;
}
int x = 0;
f(x);
//now x equals 5

int f2(int b){
 b = 5;
}
int y = 0;
f2(y);
//y still equals 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Actaully it is like this the reference part in the question was to distract u it is just   x pointed to the address of the the p but the 'x' itself contained the value 5 at the first time but the recurrsion ran for 4 times so in the stack it was like ----[x when value 6(bottom of the stack), xwhen value 7, xwhen value was 8 , x when value is 9(top of the stack)] ...at the top it was 9 but as we know that in recurrsion first loop execution takes place and then the evaluation so when the value of x changed to 9 then all the four block of the stack changed to 9 since they pointed to the same 'x'....so it came out to be 9*9*9*9=6561 ..as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

- `&` is reference: it means it must be an object's reference (address);
- `*` is a pointer: it points to a object.

The difference is that "`&x`" can not be "`NULL`", but 
`&x` can be `NULL`.

These two prototype are different.

```
int f(int & ,int );
int f(int * ,int ); //are different function prototypes
```

This is a good question.

Answer (score -3):

The code is calculating (2P-1)^(P-1)
Try various values for P to find the pattern.
Here, P=5; so it yields 9^4 = 6561.

پویا پاکاریان

پویاپاکاریان