# Type error and pointer confusion

Tags: c++, pointers, typeerror

I am trying to learn pointers and I get this error. Do I need to change the header file class Request? Why am I getting such an error?

```
cannot convert `req' from type `Request' to type `Request *'
```

The error is happening in theses lines:

```
//Store necessary information in a Request object for each request. 
Request req(url, request, 1);

Request *reqq = req; //req points to the object
list->Append(reqq);
```

code:

```
void 
ClientThread(int request)
{
  const int sz = 50;
  char url[sz];

  FILE *fp = fopen("url.txt", "r");
  if (!fp)
    printf("  Cannot open file url.txt!\n");
  else {
    int pos = 0;
    char c = getc(fp);
    while (c != EOF || pos == sz - 1) {
      if (c == '\n') {
    url[pos] = '\0';
    serve(url);
    pos = 0;

    //Store necessary information in a Request object for each request. 
    Request req(url, request, 1);

    Request *reqq = req; //req points to the object
    list->Append(reqq);

      }
      else {
    url[pos++] = c;
      }
      c = getc(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);
  }
}
```

my request.h file consist of the following:

```
class Request
{
 public:
  //constructor intializes request type

  Request(char *u, int rqtID, int rqtrID);
  char *url;
  int requestID;
  int requesterID;
```

}

Comment: `req` is a `Request`. `reqq` is a pointer to `Request`. There is no conversion from one to the other.

Comment: The address-of operator `&` is used to convert an object to a pointer: `&req`.

Comment: @MarkRansom: The `&` operator doesn't *convert* an object to a pointer. It yields a pointer value that's the address of the object.

Comment: @KeithThompson, OK you caught me using some sloppy language. Sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the [address-of operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access) here:

```
Request *reqq = &req; //req points to the object 
// -------------^
```

Note that `&` in this case [does not mean reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6877164/3920237).

> If the operand is an lvalue expression of some type T, operator&
>   creates and returns a prvalue of type T*.

Answer (score 1):

Put the reference of `req` using `&req`. A pointer type accept a pointer value, not an object.

```
Request *reqq = &req; //req points to the object
```