# C++: Dereferencing a vector<vector<class_ptr*>>

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to store classes in a 2d array, but with empty fields, or holes, i.e. fields that simply have no content. Since the class itself is quite big, I decided to fill the vector with pointers to the class, so empty fields could be simply written as NULL.
I instantly hit a Wall.
If I try to initialize the first value of the vector like this:

```
myVector[0][0]* = classToBeCopied;
```

I get the following errors:
"Syntax Error"
"expected primary-expression before '=' token"

I do have a working copy-constructor and operator= for the class.
(I am using Eclipse Luna)
Thank you in advance!

Comment: what's that `*`? Did you mean `myVector[0][0] = &classToBeCopied;`?

Comment: If you're looking to store only copies, why not declare it as `std::vector<std::vector<class_type>>` to make copy the default? Seems counter-productive to store pointers.

Comment: @Antonio I think OP is trying to dereference the pointer stored the the nested `vector` to trigger the copy assignment operator.

Comment: @Antonio ^James Adkins is correct. For various reasons it could get messy using references.

Comment: @BigBadWolf Placed there, `&` does not mean reference, but "address of". You can find a good explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877052/use-of-the-operator-in-c-function-signatures)

Comment: Oh, thank you! The usage of references in C++ has always been confusing for me, always thinking of it as addresses (To me, a reference was the same thing as an "address of"). But, if I assign it by address, doesn't that turn bad when  `classToBeCopied`s lifetime ends?

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
*myVector[0][0] = classToBeCopied;
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked. Does the asterisk positioning make a difference in C++? I'm fresh in from C.

Comment: a* = b; will try to parse as a *= b; in C too, so there is no difference in dereferencing syntax

Comment: I guess you can do something a thousand times in a row, and still get it wrong. I felt like the whitespace made it clear that it's not a *=.

Comment: @BigBadWolf I'm wondering how this solution can work for you. You said you _try to initialize the first value of the vector_ and you store pointers in your `vector` so I assume they are initialized with `0`. In this case `*myVector[0][0]` means dereferencing a null-pointer which should lead to a segmentation fault...

Comment: Jesus, I haven't even considered that yet. the [0][0] instance was created by push_back(class*), which may explain why I didn't get a segfault. I guess I will have to use `new` sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

> myVector[0][0]* = classToBeCopied;

If the result of `myVector[0][0]` is a type `class_ptr*`. Then you could do the following.

```
class_ptr* p = myVector[0][0];
*p; // Dereference
```

Therefore the following should be sufficient

```
*myVector[0][0]
```