# passing address of variable to function

Tags: c, function, pointers, parameter-passing, addressof

I am not great on pointers but I have to learn in the field. If my understanding serves me correct these should all be valid statements below.

```
int* a;
int b = 10;
a = &b;
(*a) = 20;

(*a) == b;  //this should be true
```

if you have a function like this:

```
void copy(int* out, int in) {
    *out = in;
}

int m_out, m_in;

copy(&m_out, m_in);

m_out == m_in; // this should also be true
```

but I saw a function like this

```
create(float& tp, void* form, char* title);
```

I understand the void pointer, it can be cast to anything, I understand the character pointer which is basically a c style string.

I do not understand the first argument, which is the address of some type, let's say a float but it could be anything, a struct, a int, etc.

What is going on there?

Comment: Are you sure the last snippet is C? It looks like it's C++.

Comment: This is C++ operator for reference. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877052/use-of-the-operator-in-c-function-signatures.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First this

```
int m_out, m_in;

copy(&m_out, m_in);
```

is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - you passed uninitialized vaiable `m_in` to function - and hence trying to make copy of an uninitialized variable.

This:

```
create(float& tp, void* form, char* title);
```

doesn't make sense in C. Looks like [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in) from C++.

Comment: OK! So passing a reference in c++ is just a "cleaner" way to pass by reference vs dereferencing pointers in c.

Comment: @user1610950 Yes something like that

Answer (score 0):

The first argument is a reference, it just means that if you modify this field in your function `create`, the field will still remain modified (even in the function where you called `create()`) because it points to an address and not a value.