# Passing Constant Class as argument in function

Tags: c++

what is the difference between

```
void A(const class1 a);
```

and

```
void A(const class1 &a);
```

in C++.

I am not able to differentiate these two.

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: seeking for help not for suggestions

Comment: Well one declaration have an `&` in it, the other does not. That makes a *very* big difference, one that any beginners book would tell you about.

Comment: Have you done any research on this? What has it told you and where are you stuck with its results?

Comment: Start your research here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6877052/use-of-the-operator-in-c-function-signatures

Comment: *seeking for help not for suggestions*. Really?

Comment: You shouldn't be writing C++ until you understand the difference between the two, and the way to learn the difference is from [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main difference is that

```
A(const class1 a);
```

will create a local copy of `a` inside `A` which can be expensive (from both memory and computational point of view) while

```
A(const class1 &a);
```

will not create a copy.

Therefore passing the reference (2nd version) is usually the preferred way.

Comment: the first form is not necessarily more expensive all depends of the size of class1 if it is bigger than a reference so what you are saying is true otherwise it is not.

Comment: @basslo: That's correct and that's why I wrote "can be expensive". However in my experience it is unlikely that copying a class is less expensive (from memory consumption and computation point of view) than copying a reference. It does not only depend on the size of the class but mainly on what the copy constructor does.

Comment: Generally if `sizeof(type) <= sizeof(void*)` then passing by reference or value doesn't matter.

Comment: @NathanOliver: What if the copy constructor does some complicated stuff? (I am not saying that a copy constructor *should* do this.)

Comment: @FrankPuffer There are certainly exceptions.  Almost anything that stores a pointer should be passed by reference.