# meaning of the * and & symbol

Tags: c, pointers

What do the `*` and `&` symbols mean in this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
  char *p;
  p="hello";
  printf("%s\n",*&*&p);
}
```

What does the `printf` statement do in the above program? Specifically, what does `*&*&p` mean?

Comment: Do some research. Pick up a tutorial. `printf` isn't exactly an obscure function.

Comment: I guess, the difficulties are in the pointer syntax, but also pointers aren't exactly obscure. 

Comment: This already your second question on SO and both start with "I can't understand...". Please formulate your questions more precisely. Here your question has obviously nothing to do with `printf` that you mention in the title but is about `&*&*` and things like that. Also please show the effort that you have invested before asking.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pointers in C: when to use the ampersand and the asterisk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094666/pointers-in-c-when-to-use-the-ampersand-and-the-asterisk)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `printf` will print the string `"hello"` because `&` is the `addressOf` operator which will return the address of the pointer followed by it and `*` is the `valueOf` operator which will return the value stored in the pointer address followed by it.

So in essence, the statement `*&*&p` will read

`valueOf(addressOf(valueOf(addressOf(p))))`

which will return the string `"hello"` which is stored in the actual location.

Hope this would help you!

Answer (score 9):

These:

```
*&*&
```

Are redundant and you would never encounter such ridiculous code in a real project.  The ampersand takes the address of `p`, and the asterisk `*` dereferences it to produce the original `char*`.   Back and forth we go...

Think of it as:

```
*(&(*(&p)))
```

---

As an aside, your type-less signature for `main` won't cut it on modern compilers where a return type of `int` is no longer assumed.

Comment: thankx i got it...the brackets really helped

Comment: @GhostIscuming So pointer  it is ! Though unlikely to encounter such instances but hey ,why not be prepared ? So have a look at this  [link](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html).It is sure to come in handy.