# Pointer to a 2D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am new to C programming and have been looking for this question for few days...

```
int arr[][2]={11,22,33,44,55,66};
int (*ptr)[2]=&arr[1];    //line a
int (*ptr1)[2]=arr[1];    //line b
```

For line (a) compiler has no issue but for  line (b) it gives `ERROR-cant convert int* to int[2]*`

Now both `&arr[1]` and `arr[1]` have same size(when I checked in sizeof operator).

So please help me understand what exactly is happening? what is the difference between `arr[1]` and `&arr[1]`? Thank you!

Comment: See here, it should help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094666/pointers-in-c-when-to-use-the-ampersand-and-the-asterisk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"same size" does not mean "same type". There are various types with the same size.

`arr[1]` has type `int[2]` .  So `&arr[1]` has type `int(*)[2]`, so `line a` is fine.

When you use an expression with array type and it is not the operand of `&` or `sizeof`, it undergoes lvalue-to-rvalue conversion, and the result of this conversion is a pointer to the first element of the array. (This is sometimes called *decay*).

So on `line b`, after decay, `arr[1]` is the same as `&arr[1][0]` which as type `int *`.  This is incompatible with `int (*)[2]` so that assignment fails.

The definition of *compatible type* for pointers is (paraphrased) that the type is identical. Any assignment between non-compatible pointers other than `void *` requires a cast (and probably doesn't do what you expect).

For further reading check [the C FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/)  and perhaps also search this site for highly-rated questions on the topic.

Comment: thanks a lot.I wasn't aware of this decay concept so this answer is really helpful.