# What for & is used, how is it used in this code above?

Tags: c, pointers

I don't quite get this, here is a simple program I picked from the internet written in C.

EXAMPLE 1.

```
int main(void) {

        char * b;

        memmove((char *)&b, "saaaa", 6);
        puts((char *)&b);

        return 0;
}
```

and here is my own code,
EXAMPLE 2.

```
int main(void) {


    char b[10];

    memmove(b, "baaaa", 6);
    printf("%s\n", b);

    return 0;

}
```

Why is it using `&` in EXAMPLE 1 ? I have mostly used `&` sign when I want to assign a value to the variable like in scanf(). But in EXAMPLE 1, I am not assigning it. The only thing I do is I move the string `saaaa`to the variable b.

And why using `(char *)` method is required any way?

Comment: `Char *` is not method . It is a cast .

Comment: The cast was included most likely to silence a diagnostic from the compiler.  The first example is very broken.

Comment: @FatalError  What kind of diagnostic ?

Comment: Ex1 must be a `sizeof(char*) >= 6`  as a requirement.

Comment: @ameyCU: `puts()` takes a `const char *`.  You'll get an error if you try passing a `char **`.

Comment: @FatalError Is it me, or the example doesn't even make sense. It is taking the address in memory of the pointer, instead of passing the pointer itself.

Comment: @FatalError  Yeah , in `puts` but it will unnecessary in `memmove` .

Comment: @Cubia: BLUEPIXY said it well.  You could cram a string into the value of the pointer and treat it as if it were a `char[sizeof(char*)]`.  But, I don't think I need to elaborate on why this is a questionable idea :) other than for entertainment purposes.

Comment: @ameyCU Technically, there are no methods in C.

Comment: @PCLuddite Yeah , agreed.

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand operator (`&`) is used in front of a variable to obtain the address of that variable. Doing `&b` will get the address in memory of `b`.

Here is a great SO post on when to use the ampersand : [Pointers in C: when to use the ampersand and the asterisk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094666/pointers-in-c-when-to-use-the-ampersand-and-the-asterisk)

Hope this helps.

EDIT : As FatalError has noted in the comments, your example seems broken. The best I can do is point you in the right direction on understanding these operators.