# Use of '&' in a specific C program

Tags: c

I am new to C programming, and I am trying to figure out what does the `&` do in `(&end)` in this timer but I cannot find a sufficient answer anywhere.

```
time_t end, current;
time(&end);
end += t;
```

Comment: `&` is used to pass address of `end` variable to the `time` function.

Comment: Why the C++ tag if you're asking about the C language?  They are different.  For example, the `&` symbol can be used in the C++ language to declare *references*, which C doesn't have.

Comment: I was about to downvote, thinking there'd be plenty of resources about this question; however, I was unable to find anything specific to C and the `&` in a quick search.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointers in C: when to use the ampersand and the asterisk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094666/pointers-in-c-when-to-use-the-ampersand-and-the-asterisk)

Answer (score 2):

`&` is the address-of operator. It is a unary operator with returns the address of its operand in memory (a pointer to it).

In this case, the function `time` is defined as

```
time_t time(time_t *t)
```

As you can see, `time` accepts a pointer to a `time_t` type variable. This is referred to as passing a reference (not strictly accurate, as it's really just a pointer in c but still some useful terminology). It allows `time_t` passed in to be modified directly. Basically, instead of passing in `end` you are saying "get a pointer that points at `end` and pass that in". So by calling `time(&end);`, the `time` function can set the value of `end` even though it is being passed in as a function argument.

I have to say though, some quick googling would have certainly provided a complete explanation. For more info I'd suggest looking up `c ampersand operator` and `c address-of operator`, as well as `pass by reference vs pass by value`.