# Referencing/dereferencing in C/C++

Tags: c, reference, dereference

There's an apparent discrepancy in the way pointers are used that I don't understand.

The following code is taken from [Pointers in C: when to use the ampersand and the asterisk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094666/pointers-in-c-when-to-use-the-ampersand-and-the-asterisk) :

```
void swap(int *x, int *y) {int tmp = *x; *x = *y; *y = tmp; }
...
int a = 1, b = 2;
printf("before swap: a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
swap(&a, &b);
printf("after swap: a = %d, b = %d\n", a, b);
```

The following code is taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typedef :

```
int do_math(float arg1, int arg2) {
    return arg2;
}

int call_a_func(int (*call_this)(float, int)) {
    int output = call_this(5.5, 7);
    return output;
}

int final_result = call_a_func(&do_math);
```

Here's what I don't understand:

In the first case, in order to counteract the effect of the referencing operator, the dereferencing operator is used with `x` and `y`, so in order to use them more-or-less the same way you'd use them without dereferencing if you hadn't passed them by reference, you use them with `*`'s. But in the second case, `call_this` isn't invoked using a dereferencing operator that counteracts the fact that it was passed by reference; i.e. it's not called as `(*call_this)(5.5, 7)`.

Why would you use `*`'s to counteract the effect of passing by reference so you can use the thing more-or-less as you normally would in the case of variables but not in the case of functions?

Comment: C does not support references, just pointers. C++ is a different language. And a "referencing operator" does not exist in C.

Comment: I find your usage of the phrase "counteract" very confusing. There is no counteracting of anything here. I'd recommend you grab on of the books on [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/2069064) and read through it to understand better what pointers are.

Comment: I guess my use of the word counteract was a little confusing. I just meant that if you pass a value by reference, you'll have to dereference it in order to use it normally, so the two are complementary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call function pointers as well as functions:

```
void (*a)();
void (b)();

// Both valid
a();
b();
```

Comment: thanks, does this imply that `(*call_this)(5.5, 7)` would have worked equally well in the above code?

Comment: @inhahe: yes, it does