# Making an array of char in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, assign

I am new to C,

So I tried to make a program assigning grades according to marks of students.
I need to make a char array with the first slot referring to the first student .. etc

The initialization was simple

```
char grade[n];
```

Where n is the number of students

to assign values I made a condition comparing the marks in a loop and if the condition is fulfilled this kind of statement is executed :

```
grade[i] == 'B';
```

To call the value at the end I used this :

```
printf("%c", &grade[i]);
```

Where "i" is the displaying loop control variable.

At the end, strange symbols were displayed. What is the right way to create an array of chars and calling individual "slots" ?

Comment: `==` is not an assignment operator.

Comment: `&grade[i]` is getting the *address* of index `i` in the array, which is likely to be a really big, useless number. Just use `grade[i]` to access the character at index `i` of the array.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pointers in C: when to use the ampersand and the asterisk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094666/pointers-in-c-when-to-use-the-ampersand-and-the-asterisk)

Comment: @Purag - partly.   OP also seems to be using the comparison operator (`==`) when assignment (`=`) is intended.

Comment: Thanks guys .. that really helped me so much .. I am so grateful =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this

```
printf("%c", &grade[i]);
```

to

```
printf("%c", grade[i]);
```

And it should work as you expect.

Comment: @user2217482 Can you paste your whole program in the question? We can have a look to see other problems.

Answer (score 3):

You print pointer address, don't use & in print.

Answer (score 1):

Just use printf("%c", grade[i]) without the "&" address-of operator. You want to print the character at index i, not the address of that character.