# what is wrong in this c code? The Answer is always zero?

Tags: c, debugging

I am new to c, please help, the answer to this is always zero.why? Instead of converting KM to Metres or centimetres(sorry for typos);

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float Km;
    float metres;
    float inches;
    float centimetres;

    printf("Welcome, please enter the distance in Km.\n");

    scanf("%f", &Km);
    metres = Km * 1000;
    centimetres = Km*100000;
    inches = Km*25/1000000;

    printf("Distance In Metres is:\n");
    printf("%f\n", &metres);

    printf("Distance in Centimeters is:\n");
    printf("%f\n", &centimetres);

    printf("Distance in Inches is:\n");
    printf("%f\n", &inches);

    printf("bye\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why are you sending the addresses of your variables into the printf statements>

Comment: An inch is exactly 2.54 centimetres, not 2.5.  And I don't think you should be dividing by 1000000 on that line.

Comment: Aside `inches = Km*25/1000000;` better as `inches = centimetres*2.54;`

Comment: Another aside: why are you working in `float` in 21st century? Use `double` except where very good reason not to. You don't use `short` when you can use `int` do you, except, again for a very good reason.

Comment: remove `&`  from argument of `printf`

Answer (score 2):

`printf` function writes the value of the variable. The ampersand operator `&` turns your value into a pointer and that's the error. Instead of printing the actual value of your variables, you are printing the address memory of the pointer.

Read [documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_printf.htm) on printf function. More info on `&` and `*` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094666/pointers-in-c-when-to-use-the-ampersand-and-the-asterisk).

Answer (score 1):

You are printing the *location* of the variables. The calculation is fine, but you're not actually printing the value of the variable. You're printing where it is in memory.

The `&` operator will give the location of the variable. You can fix your program by removing the `&`s in the printf statements, i.e. this:

```
printf("%f\n", &inches);
```

becomes:

```
printf("%f\n", inches);
```

Also, [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) is a link to a pretty in-depth `printf()` reference; to learn more about pointers, you can go to [this page](https://users.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave.Marshall/C/node10.html).

Comment: "If you want to print the location, ..., use a decimal or hexadecimal formatter (%d and %x" is poor advice and detracts from a good answer - recommend delete that paragraph.  `%d` is for `int`, not an address.  To print a `void *`, use `%p`.