# Reading into an array from a txt file

Tags: c, arrays, file, struct

So, I'm trying to get my program to read into an array of structs from a text file, and it compiles okay, but doesnt appear to actually be reading in the values?.. and I have no idea why. This is the relevant part of the code:

```
typedef struct Planet
{
char Planet_Name[30];
double Fuel;
double Velocity;
double Height;
double Gravity;
int Maximum_Thrust;
double Difficulty;
}Planet;


    //read the Planets from a file
    FILE* inputFile = fopen("Planets.txt", "r");
    if(inputFile == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error. File unavailable");
        exit(1);
    }

    for(j=0; j<10; j++)
    {   
        fscanf("%29s %lf %lf %lf %lf %d %lf", SolarSystem[j].Planet_Name, 
        SolarSystem[j].Fuel, SolarSystem[j].Velocity, 
        SolarSystem[j].Height, SolarSystem[j].Gravity, 
        SolarSystem[j].Maximum_Thrust, SolarSystem[j].Difficulty);
    }

    printf("Please select a planet by entering the corresponding number: 
    Mercury[0], Venus[1], Earth[2], Moon[3], Mars[4], Jupiter[5], Saturn[6], 
    Uranus[7], Neptune[8]\n");

    scanf("%d",&PlanetNum);

    printf("You have chosen %s", SolarSystem[PlanetNum].Planet_Name);
```

This is the txt file (Title: Planets.txt)

Mercury 120 50 500 12.1 30 2
Venus 120 50 500 29.1 30 6
Earth 120 50 500 32.2 30 7
Moon 120 15 50 5.3 30 2
Mars 120 50 500 12.2 30 4
Jupiter 120 50 500 81.3 30 10
Saturn 120 50 500 34.3 30 8
Uranus 120 50 500 28.5 30 5
Neptune 120 50 500 36.6 30 9
Pluto 120 50 500 2.03 30 1

Except when it runs that final printf, it doesn't actually print anything, nor does it store any data in the structs (when its called later it's all zeroes).
Ideas?

Comment: Please see: [ask] and consider preparing a [mcve].

Comment: Accept answer if you are satisfied .

Comment: I have another question.. But the website says I have to wait two days to post again..wtf? Am i right to just paste it in below the above?..

Comment: where do you get stuck.? Is in writing to file..?

Comment: @Liam: I’ve rolled your question back to its original form. If you have a new question then it needs to be posted separately, as a new question. You should upvote/accept the answer below if it helped you. This will also help to build up your reputation and unlock priveleges on the site.

Comment: How do I accept it?..
And I'm not exactly here for the long run haha
As soon as I'm done with this silly subject I'm out.. Can't wait to be rid of it.

Comment: @Liam: there is an outline of a check-mark (aka "tick" in proper English) under the up-vote/down-vote buttons next to the answer. Click on this and it should turn green. You might also want to give the answerer an up-vote while you're there, to show your appreciation for their help.

Comment: @PaulR Thanks! I'm just blind. Apparently my upvotes dont count btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is with your `fscanf` function . You have to provide `FILE pointer` (`inputFile` This context) as first argument and `&`  operator(address of Similar to `scanf` function) in front of scanning integer and float.

Try this modified `fscanf` code :-

```
fscanf(inputFile,"%s%lf%lf%lf%lf%d%lf",SolarSystem[j].Planet_Name,&SolarSystem[j].Fuel, &SolarSystem[j].Velocity, &SolarSystem[j].Height, &SolarSystem[j].Gravity,&SolarSystem[j].Maximum_Thrust, &SolarSystem[j].Difficulty);
```

Comment: Ah bugger.. I Just rechecked the tutorial video I'm watching, he sneaks it in without making a comment, thats why I missed it!

I must ask, how do you know where to put those & symbols? I usually just play around with them in my variables until the program works properly..

Comment: In simple words other that read `string` (character array) most  probably you need to use `&` operator.

Comment: @Liam [when to use ampersands and asterisks in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094666/pointers-in-c-when-to-use-the-ampersand-and-the-asterisk)

Comment: @TormundGiantsbane I had a read.. It didn't really make much sense to be honest. Programming just isnt my thing. I cant stand it

Comment: @anoopknr: I’ve rolled back your answer to the previous version, to make it consistent with the OP’s original question (before the OP radically changed it).