# how is function(char *something) and function(char &something) different?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm getting a little bit overwhelmed with pointers.

Lets say I have an array of chars

```
char arrayOfChars[50];
```

and I want to pass it to some function that will manipulate it.

The way I pass it would be by reference:

```
someFunction(char &arrayToManipulate) {}
```

but I also often see this:

```
someFunction(char *arrayToManipulate) {}
```

What's the difference between the two,

And bonus question; is there any problem if in the parameter list of someFunction, I name the local variable by the same name? I.e.

```
someFunction(char &arrayOfChars) {}
```

Many thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094666/pointers-in-c-when-to-use-the-ampersand-and-the-asterisk This should help

Comment: Lightning fast answers! @tkausl - I think it's mostly duplicate, yes. So summarize, requesting a pointer in the parameter list, gives me flexibility later in the function, if I should want it to point to something else. Whereas just pulling in the address of the variable doesn't give me that flexibility. - And the bonus question?

Comment: `is there any problem if in the parameter list of someFunction, I name the local variable by the same name?´ You can't. At least gcc and clang don't allow it, not sure whether it is actually specified in the standard or not.