# Why does printf changes the address of a function pointer?

Tags: c, printf, function-pointers, memory-address

Adressing operator inside the printf changes the address of the function pointer from a regular adress to 0x1000. Why this happens and what does it mean ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int (*fp) (int);
    printf("%p\n", (fp));
    printf("%p", (fp));
}
```

When I run this I get
`0x560cb44ce060 0x560cb44ce060`
as expected but when ı run this

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int (*fp) (int);
    printf("%p\n", (fp));
    printf("%p", &(fp));
}
```

ı get
`0x1000 0x7ffcc92c8990`
I really can not figured out what does change when I add `&` operator at the last line.

Comment: You don't initialize the pointer, it doesn't point anywhere. Local (non-static) variables *are* uninitialized. They will have *indeterminate* values.

Comment: Also note that in C++ *using* indeterminate values *in any way*, even printing them, will lead to *undefined behavior*. The code you show are not valid C++ programs. Please remember that C and C++ are two separate and very different languages.

Comment: `fp` is the function pointer. `&fp` is its address

Comment: As for the unary `&` operator, think of it as a *pointer-to* operator. `&fp` is a pointer to the variable `fp`, and will have the type `int (**fp) (int)`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pointers in C: when to use the ampersand and the asterisk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2094666/pointers-in-c-when-to-use-the-ampersand-and-the-asterisk)

Comment: @vvv444 No I ask why does the output of the first printf changes when ı add & to second printf.

Comment: @A_normal_guy Your second program print ***two different values***. Nothing "changes". If you had two different variables, `a` and `b`, would you expect them to have the same value? It's really no difference here.

Comment: @A_normal_guy First, you shouldn't print uninitialized values. You can't expect to get anything reliable form that. And in your case `fp` is  uninitialized

Comment: In memory address 0x7ffcc92c8990 I write the value 0x1000. What is the difference between 0x7ffcc92c8990 and 0x1000? One is the address, and the other is what is written there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case of using `printf` there is outputted the uninitialized pointer `fp` (its garbage value)

```
int (*fp) (int);
printf("%p\n", (fp));`
```

In the second case of using printf there is outputted the valid address of the pointer `fp` itself

```
printf("%p", &(fp));
```

So there is nothing changed. There are outputted two different entities:  the value stored in a variable (pointer) and the address of the variable itself.

Pay attention to that the conversion specifier `p` expects a pointer of the type `void *` but function pointers may not be converted to the type `void *`.

Comment: But why does the output of the first printf changes when I add & to the second printf ?

Comment: @A_normal_guy `fp` is not initialized. Printing it is undefined. Any output is "ok". The output can differ between runs and it can change when you add something seemingly unrelated to the code

Comment: So when I try to print an uninitialized variable ıt causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @A_normal_guy You are right.

Comment: @A_normal_guy The output depends on what will be stored in the memory allocated to the pointer in each run of the program. The system can load the program in different addresses.

Comment: There is actually a second UB there: function pointers cannot be cast to void*, which is what `%p` expects.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot You are right.:)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you confonded the address which pointer is pointing to and the pointer's address.

The first %p will output the address fp saved(though it is garbage value because you didn't initialized it), and the second one will output the fp's address.